# How to Queue two observables?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I am new to Angular 2. My application has a config file which lists all the api urls.

I created a locator service to load the config.json. Other services use this service to get their specific url.

```
@Injectable()
export class LocatorService {
    private config: any;
    private loadConfig: Promise<any>;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.loadConfig = this._http.get('config/config.json')
                .map(res => this.config = res.json()).toPromise();
    }

    public getConfig() {
        return this.loadConfig.then(() => this.config);
    }
}
```

I have this other service which sends an http request to a url. This service gets the url from locator service.

```
@Injectable()
export class OtherService {
    private _data: any;
    private url: string;
    constructor(private _http: Http, private locatorService: LocatorService) {
      this.geturl();
    }

    public loadData(): model[] {
      this.geturl().then(() => this._http.get()
                  .map(res => this._data  = res.json())
                  .catch(error =>
                  Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
                  .subscribe(t => this._data = t.json());

       return this._data;
    }

    private geturl() {
        return this.locatorService.getConfig().then(t => {
        this.url = t.serviceUrl;
        console.log(this.url);
        });
    }
}
```

my component call this loadData n gets the required data. How do I achieve the same?

I am not very clear how to wait for config url to be loaded then send http request and return the data.

Please help.

Comment: What's the point of using a promise here? Both requests are actually observables. And you're doing something wrong, because code above should result in sequential request. Please, provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to replicate the problem, a plunk would help.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use Promise for this meaning that `then` is not required to use `getConfig` function of your `LocatorService`. Make changes as below and make sure you have single instance for `LocatorService` in yor app and check it again :

//LocatorService

```
@Injectable()
export class LocatorService {
    private config: any = null;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        if (this.config === null ) {
          this._http.get('config/config.json')
              .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
                this.config = res;
              });
        }
    }

    public getConfig() {
        return this.config;
    }
}
```

//OtherService

```
@Injectable()
export class OtherService {
    private _data: any;
    private url: string;

    constructor(private _http: Http, private locatorService: LocatorService) {
      this.url = this.locatorService.getConfig();
    }

    public loadData(): model[] {
      return this._http.get(this.url.serviceUrl)
                  .map(res => this._data  = res.json())
                  .catch(error =>
                  Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));         
    }

}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. getConfig doesn't wait for http request to complete.

Comment: The code above adds nothing good to original code. It runs the requests in parallel, `if (this.config === null )` check is useless because a constructor runs only once per service instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use do it this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocatorService {
    private loadConfig: Promise<any>;
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        this.loadConfig = this._http.get('config/config.json')
                .map(res => this.config = res.json()).toPromise();
    }

    public getConfig() {
        return this.loadConfig;
    }
}

@Injectable()
export class OtherService {
    private _data: any;
    constructor(private _http: Http, private locatorService: LocatorService) {
    }

    public loadData() {
        Observable.from(this.locatorService.getConfig())
            .switchMap((config) => this._http.get(config.serviceUrl))
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
            .subscribe(t => this._data = t.json());
    }
}
```